# Will an opossum wake up from pain stimulus if playing dead?

Tags: animal-behaviour, opossums

When an opossum is playing dead, will it keep up the act even if an animal decides to start eating it anyways? Or will it wake up once it's flesh starts getting ripped open and try to fight back or flee?

Comment: After some googling, I think this question might be answerable only by a vet, an anesthesiologist or a wildlife expert. The sources I have looked at just say that animals don't try to eat a possum "playing dead". See also [Apparent Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_death) for two reported cases of orcas inducing tonic immobility (TI) (another term for apparent death) in (1) a great white shark and (2) a stingray. The shark was suffocated while in TI and the stingray eaten.

Comment: @ab2 Don't forget scavengers. I think they'll try to eat it anyway.

Comment: @OddDeer According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opossum#Behavior): `When an opossum is "playing possum", the animal's lips are drawn back, the teeth are bared, saliva foams around the mouth, the eyes close or half-close, and a foul-smelling fluid is secreted from the anal glands.`. Maybe this deters even scavengers?

Comment: Oh, and I found [this link](http://animals.mom.me/opossums-playing-dead-5274.html) saying that `the opossum's body emits green mucus that will discourage most predators from feeding on him while he's in his comatose state`. Can we consider it a reputable source?

Comment: @Roflo I'm not asking about what *most* predators or scavengers will do with an opossum that's playing dead, the question is will an opossum wake up if it's act doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was trying to see if we could improve the community answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Partial Answer: Needs Input from Others**

Following the suggestion of @OddDeer that scavengers would eat a possum playing dead, I did a bit of searching.  The information in this source suggests that nobody will eat a live possum that is playing dead.  But this is not definitive.

From [What will eat an opossum?](https://retrieverman.net/2009/09/23/what-will-eat-an-opossum/), September 23, 2009 by retrieverman

> I’ve seen opossum carcasses lie in open fields where foxes and coyotes
>   frequent, and they don’t touch them.  I keep reading that foxes and
>   coyotes eat them, but I’ve not seen it. Dogs will kill them, but
>   that’s all they will do.
>
> I’ve heard of coyotes raiding opossums stealing opossums from leg hold
>   traps.
>
> I’ve not seen it........
>
> When an opossum dies, it usually rots until the turkey vultures show
>   up. And then they eat it. They aren’t as picky as dogs, foxes, and
>   coyotes are.

But this raises the question:  If a turkey vulture will eat a thoroughly dead possum, why won't it try to eat a possum playing possum (which looks and smells dead), and if it does, what will the possum do?

I can only speculate that a scavenger can distinguish a truly rotten carcass from the simulated decay that the possum produces; the simulated decay fools non-scavengers but does not fool scavengers. This would be a survival trait for the possum.  This still doesn't answer the OP's question about pain stimulus.